# Batch file to delete all folders in a directory except a specified list

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

I'm looking for a batch file that will go into C:\Documents and Settings\ and delete all folders except a few that I want to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hack-around =D

If you have a list of folder paths in say folders.txt listed as so:

- C:\Documents and Settings\Mechaflash
- C:\Documents and Settings\Mom
- C:\Documents and Settings\Dad

etc. What you can do is temporarily change them to hidden folders, then RMDIR on all non-hidden folders.

```
CD "C:\Documents and Settings\"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (folders.txt) DO (
 ATTRIB +H "%%A" /S /D
)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`DIR /B /A:-HD "C:\Documents and Settings\"`) DO (
 RMDIR /S /Q %%A
)
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (folders.txt) DO (
 ATTRIB -H "%%A" /S /D
)
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using robocopy:

```
cd /d "C:\Documents and Settings"
md tmp
robocopy . tmp /E /MOVE /XD folderToKeep1 folderToKeep2 ...
rd /s /q tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rem the last space character is deliberate
set yourKeepList="abc def "
for /f %%f in ('dir /b/ad "C:\Documents and Settings"') do (
    (echo %yourKeepList% | findstr /v /i "%%f " 1>nul) && rd /q/s %%f
)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work properly; I did include the space.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or is it that this didn't remove directories that you expected?

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings>((echo "keepList.txt "   | findstr /v /i "test "  1>nul )  && rd /q/s f )
The system cannot find the file specified.