# How to delete (remove) specific folders and files in a drive?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have to “clean” a 2 TB network drive shared by all the members of my office. Some of the folders are still in use, but most of them are old folders created by former members of my team. Our drive is full and I need to delete all the folders/files that are not in use any more. I have the list of all the folders in use by the current members of my team and I’d like to create a batch program in which I specify what folders not to delete. I checked the DOS commands `rd`, `rmdir`, and `delete` but I see that none of them would do what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete all folders in a directory except a specified list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7504037/3033053)

Comment: Show some example lines from your list - edit your question and add them.  The way a solution works will depend on how the list has been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code that shows how to exclude a limited number of folders from `DIR`.

To see size of folders in Documents, excluding music, video, or pictures folders.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```